# unable to get xpath of anchor element under span element

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, text

I have already learned to use xpath but i am kind of stuck here - http://phptravels.com/requirements/. Can anyone please tell me how to find xpath of "Demo" hyperlink on this website. I simply used `//a[text()= 'Demo                 ']`. keep whitespaces in mind.

Comment: post the style and code in here.

Comment: //span/a[contains(text(), 'Demo')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind the xpath with an `id` which is persistent, you can consider using this xpath:

```
//nav[@id='main-menu']/ul/li/span/span/a[contains(text(), 'Demo')]
```

Comment: I need to know the issue with my code - //a[text()= 'Demo                 ']

Comment: @AshishSingh Your question header is `unable to get xpath of anchor element under span element`. IMO you should Accept an Answer which works/helps you for the Question asked. You can always raise a new Question with your new requirement asking for Documentation and Explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The white space is your problem. Use `contains` instead of equality

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Demo')]
```

Or

```
//a[contains(., 'Demo')]
```

Comment: I did use contains and it is working. The issue is that it should work with this - //a[text()= 'Demo                 '] as well.

Comment: @AshishSingh Not necessarily. `=` check exact match. Even the smallest difference will cause this check to fail. In your case the blank part is actually in a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Here with equals, but better to use contains (or starts-with), as described @Guy

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Demo\n                ']")).getText();
```

to get real text value of element - you can use this:

```
driver.findElement(webElement).getAttribute("text")
```